# Empty class size in python

Tags: python

I just trying to know the rationale behind the empty class size in python, In C++ as everyone knows the size of empty class will always shows 1 byte(as far as i have seen) this let the run time to create unique object,and i trying to find out what size of empty class in python:

```
class Empty:pass # i hope this will create empty class
```

and when i do

```
import sys
print ("show",sys.getsizeof(Empty)) # i get 1016
```

I wonder why the `Empty` takes this much 1016(bytes)? and also does the value(1016) it returns is this a standard value that never change(mostly) like C++?, Do we expect any zero base class optimization from python interpreter?Is there any way we can reduce the size of am Empty(just for curiosity sake)?

Comment: It returns `104` on my machine.

Comment: I ran my code on this https://repl.it/languages/python3

Comment: `104` if you are on Python2.x

Comment: It's not really empty, it inherits `object` which already comes with some baggage. Look at `dir(Empty)`, it's not an empty list!

Comment: Jon, yes it shows methods, does the method count in size?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume you are running a 64 bit version of Python 3. On 32 bit Python 3.6 (on Linux), your code prints `show 508`.

However, that's the size of the class object itself, which inherits quite a lot of things from the base `object` class. If you instead get the size of an *instance* of your class the result is much smaller. On my system,

```
import sys

class Empty(object):
    pass

print("show", sys.getsizeof(Empty()))
```

**output**

```
show 28
```

which is a *lot* more compact. :)

FWIW, on Python 2.6.6, `sys.getsizeof(Empty)` returns 448 for a new-style class, and a measly 44 for an old-style class (one that doesn't inherit from `object`). `sys.getsizeof(Empty())` returns 28 for a new-style class instance and 32 for an old-style.

---

You can reduce the size of an instance by using [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__slots__)

> This class variable can be assigned a string, iterable, or sequence of
>   strings with variable names used by instances. `__slots__` reserves
>   space for the declared variables and prevents the automatic creation
>   of `__dict__` and `__weakref__` for each instance.

```
import sys

class Empty(object):
    __slots__ = []

print("show", sys.getsizeof(Empty()))
```

**output**

```
show 8
```

Please read the docs to understand how to use this feature.

Comment: PM, when i do dir(Empty) the most of the things i could see is operators/methods, does the method does count in size()?

Comment: @Richard_G. The actual code of the method isn't counted, but the _pointer_ to the method is counted. Similarly, if you call `sys.getsizeof` on a list you only get the size of the list object itself plus the size of all the pointers to the objects referenced in the list; `sys.getsizeof` is _not_ recursive.

Comment: PM, when i add methods in Empty the size is same(so does the method really count)?

Comment: @Richard_G The pointers to the methods (and any other attributes) you add are going into the object's `__dict__`, so they aren't directly visible to `sys.getsizeof`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Apr 12 2016, 14:09:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
>>> class Empty:pass
>>> import sys
>>> print ("show",sys.getsizeof(Empty)) # i get 1016
('show', 104)
>>> print ("show",sys.getsizeof(Empty()))
('show', 72)
```

Not 1016 bytes. As you can see, this is implementation specific. Other interesting sizes, using new-style classes:

```
>>> print ("show",sys.getsizeof(object())) 
('show', 16)
>>> class Empty2(object):pass
>>> print ("show",sys.getsizeof(Empty2)) 
('show', 904)
>>> print ("show",sys.getsizeof(Empty2())) 
('show', 64)
```

An empty class definition is still a class definition and hence a class object ([more here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax)):

> When a class definition is entered, a new namespace is created, and used as the local scope ..
>
> When a class definition is left normally (via the end), a class object is created. This is basically a wrapper around the contents of
>   the namespace created by the class definition ...

All class objects have a minimal set of attributes, which you see by doing:

```
    >>> dir(Empty)
['__doc__', '__module__']
>>> dir(Empty2)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

And also other implementation details, which is the reason for their larger than naively-expected size.

Finally, note that that the class *instances* are indeed rather small, as expected, and not as big as class *objects*. `Empty` is a class object. `Empty()` is a class instance.